# Pagination issues - kaminari - Posts on User's controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, pagination

I am having a hard time with Kaminari pagination on my application.  Refer to the code below

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController

def show
 @posts = Post.where(:user_id => @user.id).order("created_at DESC").page(params[:page]).per(3)                                           
end
```

**undefined method `per' for Post::ActiveRecord_Relation:0x007f9eafa014a0>**

Basically when I go to the User's show page, I have a section dedicated to show all the user's posts that I wanted to paginate.  (3 per section)

The @posts works when I take out the per(3) part but when i use the **<%= paginate @posts %>** on my views I get

**undefined method `paginate'**

Here is my Gemfile:

```
gem 'simple_form', '~> 3.1.0' 
gem 'rails', '4.2.0' 
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0' 
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0' 
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.1.0' 
gem 'jquery-rails' 
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0' 
gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0', group: :doc gem "paperclip", "~> 4.2" 
gem 'omniauth-facebook' 
gem 'omniauth-instagram' 
gem 'figaro' 
gem 'acts_as_votable', '~> 0.10.0' 
gem 'kaminari', '~> 0.16.3'
```

Not sure how to go about this as I didn't see anything similar to my issue.  Thank you!

Comment: I suppose you would have already done this. But no harm in clarifying. Did you follow the installation procedure(running the generators, nothing else) mentioned in the kaminari readme ? Run bundle install ?

Comment: Would you also post your Gemfile to help?

Comment: @TiagoFarias `gem 'simple_form', '~> 3.1.0'
gem 'rails', '4.2.0'
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.1.0'
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'
gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0', group: :doc
gem "paperclip", "~> 4.2"
gem 'omniauth-facebook'
gem 'omniauth-instagram'
gem 'figaro'
gem 'acts_as_votable', '~> 0.10.0'
gem 'kaminari', '~> 0.16.3'` Sorry I'm not sure how to format this correctly

Comment: `group :test, :development do
  gem 'rspec-rails'
  gem 'capybara'
  gem 'selenium-webdriver'
  gem 'better_errors'
  gem 'binding_of_caller'
  gem 'factory_girl_rails'
  gem 'simplecov'
  gem 'database_cleaner'
  gem 'sqlite3'
  gem 'pry'
  gem 'guard-rspec', require: false
  gem 'thin'
end` More in my development (due to character limitation)

Comment: You can edit your post and put the things there like I just did there.

Answer (score 0):

There may be a conflict with the method `page` from other gems. Try creating a file kaminari.rb in config/initializers, with this:

```
Kaminari.configure do |config|
  config.page_method_name = :per_page_kaminari #or whatever other than page or per
end
```

If it doesn't work, try the next approach [here](https://github.com/activeadmin/activeadmin/issues/1833).

Comment: I'm not sure what I did to fix to get it working.. The code did not change